Rendering Issues in Motorola G Play 2023 for Flutter App
We are experiencing rendering issues with our Flutter app on a Motorola G Play 2023 phone. Despite trying various solutions, including modifying the theme, the issues persist. We would appreciate any help or guidance on resolving this problem. Thank you in advance.
[

can you please share which flutter sdk version are you using

@HitarthChhunchha  we are using 3.19.3
